# Sign up for Openshift Online with voip number?

Tags: openshift

I'm trying to sign up for Openshift Online, and it wants my phone number.  However, it identifies my Republic Wireless number as a VOIP number for whatever reason, and gives me an error that I need a different number.  After 3 attempts, it says.

We're sorry for any difficulties you've encountered, but we're unable to further verify your account.
If you are having problems, please contact support.

I've contacted support, but I'm hoping there's an easier way.  It's the same if I try to sign up for a $50 a month account.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not OpenShift support. This Q&A site for programming questions.

Comment: True, but this is where the Openshift site points me to get answers, so it's likely that the next person with a VOIP problem will need to know what works.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, the openshift support person was able to manually confirm my account and keep me moving.  Just needed to open a ticket.